# Make php session active OR if logout return to previous page

Tags: php

Using the following php  script. How I make active the session till the user logout. Its logging out every 30 min(approximately). OR if logout user redirect to the last page visted.

```
 <?PHP
 require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

 if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
 { $loggedin="0";} else { $loggedin="1"; }
 if ($loggedin=="1") {echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
 window.alert('You are already signed in. Please continue to use')
 window.history.back();
 </SCRIPT>");
 exit; }

 if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
 {
 if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
 $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("Upload.php");
 }
 }
 ?>


  function CheckLogin()
  {
     session_start();

     $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: This script shows nothing about your session handling logic.

Comment: check login...is there

Comment: Yes but the code you are showing is just showing methods calls against `$fgmembersite` object. This tells us nothing about your logic for starting/destroying sessions or how that relates to logins. We have no idea what those methods do. You need to show more context.

Comment: Maybe you have to unset and destroy the user session

Answer (score 0):

That's a PHP config issue. If you don´t have any access to the php.ini file or don´t wanna mess with it, what you can do is that every time you enter a page you save the current page in a table on the database (it should have a relation with the user table), and when the user log outs after the 30min limit, you just retrieve that value from the database.

You can get the current URL with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. To check if the user logout just save a session variable and everytime the page is load do:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    // redirect to the page in the database table
    header("Location: ".$field_from_db);
}
```

Hope it helps!